# WSL2 not accessible through Windows, but works fine through terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running Ubuntu through WSL2 with no real problems until today. As I was coding in my Jupyter notbook (server running in WSL2, accessed through Firefox on Windows), I started to get strange errors, and realised that my ubuntu terminal windows had all closed. I don't know if I misclicked and closed them, or if they terminated themselves.

I re-opened a terminal and launched the Jupyter server again, and it works but has some strange behaviour. It looks as though it basically gives up while running scripts. It will be running a chunk of code, with the `[*]` and showing output underneath, and then with no apparent reason it will stop running. In the terminal window running the server, it will tell me that the kernel has restarted, but there is no error message or any further explanation.

After restarting my PC, Jupyter now seems to be working fine, and I can use the Ubuntu system normally through a terminal.

However, now I cannot access the files on the WSL2 mount through Windows at all (it seems). I've tried opening a folder in Windows Explorer, which just loads eternally without responding, and opening a file in Excel, which it fails to do (with no error message, it just doesn't load). Trying to browse through my files in the Excel "open file" browser also does not work, it produces the same behaviour as for the Windows file explorer.

I have tried restarting my PC as well as forcing the wsl shutdown through Windows Powershell, but the problem persists. What is happening? And if it's still unclear, what error logs should I look for to start to solve this problem?

Comment: Since this is more about a problem with WSL than a programming question, you'll probably be better off deleting this here and reposting on [Super User](https://superuser.com).  It would be (a) more on-topic there and (b) more likely to have the right expertise there for troubleshooting this with you.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Just posted it over there. I wasn't too sure to start with, but I'd gotten an answer concerning wsl2 on here before. Thanks for the advice!